# MongoDB Compass Community 1.16.3 $match issue with ObjectId + ISODate

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, aggregation, mongodb-compass

I am trying to build an `aggregation` on **MongoDB Compass Community 1.16.3** and I have a strange issue on the `$match` stage querying `ObjectId` and `ISODate` at the same time.

### The non working *$match* stage

```
{
  user_id: ObjectId("5c9168ec5530c90d0c5cd98a"),
  value: {$gte: 600},
  datetime: { $gte: ISODate("2019-02-01T00:00:00Z"), $lt: ISODate("2019-04-10T23:59:59Z") }
}
```

This query does not work at all and Compass return `Expected end of input but "}" found.`

[image]

### But these *$match* stages work

```
{
  user_id: ObjectId("5c9168ec5530c90d0c5cd98a"),
  value: {$gte: 600}
}
```

Perfect result!

```
{
  value: {$gte: 600},
  datetime: { $gte: ISODate("2019-02-01T00:00:00Z"), $lt: ISODate("2019-04-10T23:59:59Z") }
}
```

Perfect result!

It seems that the query does not work if I use `ObjectId` and `ISODate` at the same time. So, did I made a mistake somewhere? Or do I have to split it in 2 `$match` stages? Any thoughts?

## Edited

If I split the pipeline in 2 `$match` stages *(I removed `value` in this example)*, it works well but I don't know if it is a good practice and if it is efficient!

```
[{
    $match: {
        user_id: ObjectId("5c9168ec5530c90d0c5cd98a")
    }
}, {
    $match: {
        datetime: {
            $gte: ISODate("2019-02-01T00:00:00Z"),
            $lt: ISODate("2019-04-01T00:00:00Z")
        }
    }
}]
```

Comment: In the match condition
 {
  value: {$gte: 600},
  datetime: { $gte: ISODate("2019-02-01T00:00:00Z"), $lt: ISODate("2019-04-10T23:59:59Z") }
}, are you getting document with 
user_id: ObjectId("5c9168ec5530c90d0c5cd98a") ?

Comment: Yes, for this query I am getting all the documents in between the dates including those relative to user_id: ObjectId("5c9168ec5530c90d0c5cd98a")

Comment: What version of compass are you using?

Comment: It's version 1.16.3 - I should try to install the latest version (1.17.x) to see if there is a difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue comes from the version of MongoDB Compass Community I was using (1.16.3).

> To solve it, **update to the latest version or above: 1.17.0**

Now, the following works perfectly!

```
{
  user_id: ObjectId("5c9168ec5530c90d0c5cd98a"),
  value: {$gte: 600},
  datetime: { $gte: ISODate("2019-02-01T00:00:00Z"), $lt: ISODate("2019-04-10T23:59:59Z") }
}
```